# How to save core dump without running process in gdb

Tags: gdb, coredump

Is it possible to dump core file without running process on gdb? The process I'm running is ending too fast, gdb cannot reach his speed.

Comment: "the process is ending too fast" -- you can control the process with GDB from the start. You need to describe your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

did you try running the process from gdb :

gdb 
then execute
run 
from gdb terminal

take the backtrace once it gives segmentation fault.

Comment: How can I do this? Can you paste here commands please?

Comment: lets say your executable name is "myexe",  
execute "gdb myexe",  
a gdb prompt will come,  
then from gdb prompt execute "run <any runtime parameters>",  
for example : -l 0-1 -n 2 -m 512,  
l,m,n be the arguments that you want to pass to executable